# Acer Aspire no network controller

Tags: ethernet, acer-aspire

Our company just recently purchased an acer aspire x3950. At one point, the internet apparently worked. Now there is no internet working. The network is setup fine, but one thing I noticed is that there is no network controller in the device manager. I downloaded the driver for this computer and installed it, and it said at the end could not find realtek ethernet controller. What should I do at this point?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you install another network card just to check if your lan port is faulty

Comment: do you mean to actually purchase a new network card?

Comment: Look this system seems to be under warranty, i would suggest that you call the company to look into this as you could void your warranty. Another suggestion is to check the if your lan card is really from realtek, use a computer diagnostic software like everest (follow the link) - http://www.lavalys.com/products/ to find out the make of your network adapter. It really just might be a driver issue.

Comment: another thing did the computer ship with the driver cd? if it did try installing the driver from there. Also there are 2 realtek drivers on the website try installing both.

Comment: Is resetting the system to the factory defaults an option? If so, reboot and press `Alt+F10` (or was it `Alt+F11`?) as soon as you see the Acer logo. You can restore the system to the way it was when you got it, complete with proper drivers. (Of course then you will need to try to figure out *why* it was removed...)